# Understanding v8/Node.js profiling report

Tags: node.js, profiling, v8

I'm trying to use `--prof` option with Node.js. So I get the following report after linux-tick-processor:

```
 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  20736   94.8%    0.0%  b78a5000-b78a6000
    574    2.6%    0.0%  /usr/lib/libv8.so.3.4.14.21
    117    0.5%    0.0%  /usr/bin/node
     62    0.3%    0.0%  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so
      1    0.0%    0.0%  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      3    0.0%    0.8%  Stub: StringAddStub
      3    0.0%    0.8%  Builtin: A builtin from the snapshot {1}

 ...

   ticks parent  name
  20736   94.8%  b78a5000-b78a6000

    574    2.6%  /usr/lib/libv8.so.3.4.14.21
     94   16.4%    Function: ~QueryCommand.toBinary /storage/hoc/nodejs/lib/mongodb/commands/query_command.js:37
     94  100.0%      Function: ~Connection.send /storage/hoc/nodejs/lib/mongodb/connection.js:353
     94  100.0%        Function: ~Db.executeCommand /storage/hoc/nodejs/lib/mongodb/db.js:629

 ...
```

What is the `b78a5000-b78a6000`? Numbers in this line are different on each run.

What do columns `total`, `nonlib`, `parent` mean? I can't find docs on it.

Comment: b78a5000-b78a6000 is VDSO. linux-tick-processor does not grok it.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this question is now obsolete. I am also interested in profiling my node application, but there no longer is a `--prof` switch (which seems to get crude information anyway).

Look for `dtrace` and `flamegraph` if you use Unix (such as Solaris). Very detailed profiling. Unfortunately, I cannot use it because I run Linux (Ubuntu) and the original `dtrace` is not properly ported yet.

Comment: Thanks for notice. I'm using Linux too and the issue is not resolved (project is still frozen because of the performance). It think there should be another solution. Also, I tried `nanotime` for profiling. It was enough to determine that the problem is outside of my code.

Comment: There is now. It was not part of the precompiled binary in `Ubuntu` until `12.10` or something.